# No internet access despite good wifi signal strength, DNS server not responding

Tags: windows-8, dns, internet-connection

I am using a Sony Vaio SVE series laptop with Windows 8. I tried using the internet via wifi for the first time ever. Although it's showing good signal strength and getting connected, there is this DNS error saying "DNS server is not responding". The IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity say there is no internet access. I have tried disabling the firewall, I do not think it is a problem caused by any antivirus because I don't have one as yet. I have run the `ipconfig /all` and here are the results. How can I get internet access?

```
C:\Users\>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MESRONVAIO
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-3E-8E-B3-F3-C6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1A-3E-8E-B3-F3-C5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Speedport_W_723V_1_26_000
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Net
work Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-3E-8E-B3-F3-C5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Speedport_W_723V_1_26_000
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 54-53-ED-2A-F6-AA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: *"I do not think it is a problem caused by any antivirus because I don't have one as yet."* Instant classic. :D

Answer (score 0):

Connect to a wireless network that provides Internet access instead of one that doesn't.